# selecting an item opens edit mode in windows 8 apps C#.net

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have a windows 8 app, in which i show the list of students as tiles. When a tile is tapped on, the app bar opens which give the option to edit. My question is; when the tile is tapped, is it fine to go to the Edit window rather than opening the app bar. Does windows 8 app guidelines allow this.

I have gone through the windows 8 guidelines but it has left me confused if its the right way or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your app bar doesn't have any other options except edit then you should redirect user directly to edit screen by tapping directly.

Comment: Thanks Xyroid.
The App bar has Add and Edit.. On Add, new Student window opens up. I also had another question, should all the other windows work the same way ie, tap should open edit. because in other screens there are more than edit options on the app bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this must be that on click of the tile you should open the edit window. And the appbar must have only add button, so that in case the user wants to add a student he can do so through the app bar. I feel this is the correct user experience.